# Solr dataimporthandler use storedProcedure in deltaImportQuery

Tags: sql-server-2008, solr, dataimporthandler

I was wondering if its possible to call a storedProcedure in the deltaImportQuery.
This is what I 'm trying to do.

```
  <entity name="entity1" transformer="RegexTransformer" pk="id"
            query="SELECT * FROM table1
             INNER JOIN tabl2 ON table2.tbl1Id = table1.id"

        deltaImportQuery="exec populatetable2 ${dih.delta.id}"          

        deltaQuery="select id from table1 where dtmodified > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
 </entity>

ALTER PROCEDURE (@col1 int)
AS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM table2 WHERE tbl1Id = col1
   INSERT INTO table2 (col1,col2) Values(1,2)
   SELECT * FROM table2
END
```

In my store procedure I am deleting n rows and inserting them back. And then finally run a select statement to get some data back from the delta import query.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible in solr or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer would be yes.

Have you tried / got any errors?  If yes, please take a look at : [calling stored procedure from solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824072/calling-stored-procedure-from-solr)

You may want to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of the stored procedure.