# Dynamic TableName SOLR data import handler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm looking to configure SOLR to query a table based on certain data.
I unfortunately have to work with how the Database is setup, but here's what I'm after.

I have a table named Company that will contain a certain "prefix" value.
I want to use that prefix value to determine what tables I should query for the DIH.

As a quick sample:

```
<entity name="company" query="Select top 1 prefix from Company">
<field name="prefix" column="prefix"/>
<entity name="item" query="select * from ${company.prefix}item">
<field column="ItemID" name="id"/>
<field column="Description" name="description/>
</entity>
</entity>
```

However I only ever seem to get 1 document processed despite that table containing over 200,000 rows.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure what db are you using, but can't you embed the table selecting part of the query into the main query itself? then it would be easy

Comment: I'm using MSSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could achieve this by:

1. using an stored procedure. You can call a sp from DIH as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824072/calling-stored-procedure-from-solr)
2. inside the stored procedure, you can do the table lookup as needed, and then return the results from the real query.

Depending on how good you are with MSSql-s SQL, you might be able to just put everything into a single SQL query and use that directly in DIH, but not sure about that.

Comment: I ended up using something along the lines of:
I ended up using something along the lines of:

`declare @tablename nvarchar(50) set @tablename = 'select * from [' +  (select top 1 prefix from Company) + 'item]'; EXECUTE sp_executesql @tablename`