# Apache Solr: How to make execution of a query in a sub-entity dependent on a field from the main entity

Tags: sql, solr, dataimporthandler

How can I make the execution of a query in a sub-entity dependent on a field 
value from the main entity?

So as you can see in the (simplified) data config below, there's an entity 
`categories_lvl_0` which holds an expensive query. I ONLY want to execute 
this query if: searchobject.objecttype=115

I tried making the `categories_lvl_0` dependent on an if statement: `IF (${searchobject.objecttype}=115)`, I tried both with and without wrapping the query in a `BEGIN...END`, but all these options throw the error:

> Processing Document # 1 at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:266)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:487)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:468)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable
>   to execute query: IF (1=115)      SELECT slug_nl as slug_nl_0,slug_en
>   as slug_en_0,label_nl as label_nl_0,label_en as label_en_0    FROM
>   articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK)    INNER JOIN products_category_mapping
>   pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id    INNER JOIN products gp on
>   gp.id=pcm.artikelid    WHERE gp.artikelnummer='1000' AND ga.catlevel=0

How can I configure this?

```
<dataConfig> 
<dataSource name="ds-sql" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb" user="myuser" password="mypwd" /> 

<document name="searchobjects"> 
    <entity name="searchobject" pk="id" dataSource="ds-sql" query="SELECT c.objecttype,c.id,c.title FROM locations c UNION SELECT 115 as objecttype,c.id,c.title FROM products c">  
        <field name="id" column="id" /> 
        <field name="objecttype" column="objecttype" /> 
        <field name="title" column="title" /> 

        <entity name="categories_lvl_0" dataSource="ds-sql" query="SELECT slug_nl as slug_nl_0,slug_en as slug_en_0,label_nl as label_nl_0,label_en as label_en_0 
        FROM articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN products_category_mapping pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id 
        INNER JOIN products gp on gp.id=pcm.artikelid 
        WHERE gp.artikelnummer='${searchobject.id}' AND ga.catlevel=0"> 
        </entity>   
    </entity> 
</document> 
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like writing more complex SQL in data-config is not possible so I ended up calling a stored procedure with parameters. In the stored procedure I can write more complex logic. Data-config sample:

```
<entity name="categories_lvl_0" dataSource="ds-sql" query="[_getSolrProductCategoriesLvl0] '${searchobject.objecttype}', '${searchobject.id}'"> 
</entity>
```

More details here: [calling stored procedure from solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824072/calling-stored-procedure-from-solr)